# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la columna core_perfil.guarantee_policy

Tags: python, django, migration

Estoy intentando crear un nuevo campo en mi modelo perfil (el cuál esta relacionado en unos context processors) y me sale ese error. Lo raro es que días antes ya le había agregado otros campos y me corrió la migración sin problema alguno. Este era mi modelo antes:

```
class Perfil(ClaseModelo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Nombre')
    legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Nombre', null=True, blank=True)
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name='NIT', null=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Logo', null=True, blank=True)
    #slogan = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Eslogan', null=True, blank=True)
    #legalRep = models.CharField(max_length=65, verbose_name='Representante legal', null=True, blank=True)
    iva = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='IVA', max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=19.00)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Ciudad', null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name='Dirección', null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Teléfono', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Correo electrónico', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Perfil'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Perfil'
        ordering = ['id']
```

Y este es el modelo con el nuevo campo:

```
class Perfil(ClaseModelo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Nombre')
    legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Nombre', null=True, blank=True)
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name='NIT', null=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Logo', null=True, blank=True)
    #slogan = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Eslogan', null=True, blank=True)
    #legalRep = models.CharField(max_length=65, verbose_name='Representante legal', null=True, blank=True)
    iva = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='IVA', max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=19.00)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Ciudad', null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name='Dirección', null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Teléfono', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Correo electrónico', null=True, blank=True)
    guarantee_policy = models.TextField(verbose_name='Politica de garantía', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Perfil'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Perfil'
        ordering = ['id']
```

Cuando intento hacer el makemigrations me sale el error que menciono en el titulo. Este es el traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: no existe la columna core_perfil.guarantee_policy
LINE 1: ...s", "core_perfil"."phone", "core_perfil"."email", "core_perf...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\pdgInventarios\pdgInventarios\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    re_path('ventas/', include('applications.ventas.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\pdgInventarios\applications\ventas\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\pdgInventarios\applications\ventas\views.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .forms import (
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\pdgInventarios\applications\ventas\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    perfil = Perfil.objects.first()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 678, in first
    for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 287, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la columna core_perfil.guarantee_policy
LINE 1: ...s", "core_perfil"."phone", "core_perfil"."email", "core_perf...
```

He estado buscando información al respecto, pero no he encontrado nada para solucionarlo. Aquí dejo el código de los context processors por si sirven de algo:

```
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Perfil

def user_profile(request):
    profile_pic = getattr(request.user,'profilePic', None)
    if profile_pic is None or not profile_pic:
        profile_pic = f'{settings.STATIC_URL}img/user.png'
    else:
        profile_pic = profile_pic.url
    return{"user_pic": profile_pic}

def empresa_profile(request):
    perfil = Perfil.objects.first()

    if perfil is None:
        logo = f'{settings.STATIC_URL}img/muestra-logo.png'
        name = 'Nombre de tu empresa'
        iva = 19.00
    else:
        name = perfil.name
        iva = perfil.iva
        if perfil.logo is None or not perfil.logo:
            logo = f'{settings.STATIC_URL}img/muestra-logo.png'
        else:
            logo = perfil.logo.url
        
    return{"profile": {'logo':logo, 'name':name, 'iva':iva}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese problema surge por invocar en alguna parte la propiedad que aún no existe en base de datos. Deberás comentar esa sección del código si quieres hacer la migración.

Verifica cómo estás manipulado el objeto `Perfil` en `views` o `forms`. Cualquier lugar donde estés haciendo un llamado específico a tu propiedad o que haga una iteración de propiedades, que las confirme, que las manipule de alguna forma te puede traer problemas.

Como pista, mira esta sección del error que te devuelve:

```py
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\pdgInventarios\applications\ventas\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\pdgInventarios\applications\ventas\views.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .forms import (
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\pdgInventarios\applications\ventas\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    perfil = Perfil.objects.first()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Programacion_Django\ProyectosDjango\Entornos\pdgEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 678, in first
    for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
```